# react native build error: package android.support.annotation does not exist import android.support.annotation.Nullable ^

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm trying to make build of my app but getting error
package android.support.annotation does not exist import android.support.annotation.Nullable. I just got that error but it's working fine few hours ago

in that file

```
package com.gettipsi.stripe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by remer on 11/8/17.
 */

public class RedirectUriReceiver extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (StripeModule.getInstance() == null) {
      sendResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    }

    StripeModule.getInstance().processRedirect(getIntent().getData());
    sendResult(RESULT_OK);
  }

  private void sendResult(int resultCode) {
    setResult(resultCode);
    finish();
  }
}
```

builde.gralde file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"
        RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
// task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
//    gradleVersion = '2.0' //version required
// }
```

it's working fine few hours ago but why I'm getting that error now. Anyone know why?

Comment: have you managed to solve the problem? I have stacked in the same place.

Comment: open android folder in android studio then open that file and import nullable from androidx